# gcc const and optimization across function calls

Tags: c, gcc

Consider this code, compiled with `gcc` and `-Ofast`:

```
int f1(const char *p) {
    if (!p[0])
        return 0;

    f2(); //not inlined

    if (p[0]) { //not optimized out
        //do something
        return 0;
    } else {
        //do something else
        //not optimized out
        return 1;
    }
}
```

how can I get behavior where the second test and lower branch are optimized out (since `p[0]` is `const` and has already been tested)?

Comment: `const` does not have much to do with optimization.

Comment: @M.M. const tells the compiler to make assumptions about variables which can help optimisation choices during compilation. But I can concede that this is not its primary purpose.

Comment: @cdcdcd: I'm afraid your claim only holds for objects defined as `const` qualified, not for pointers defined as pointing to `const` objects.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for the compiler to assume that function `f2` may not modify what `p` is pointing to.  The fact that `p` is defined as `const char *p` only tells the compiler that `p` cannot be used to modify the data it points to, not that the data itself is constant.

If you know the array is indeed not modified by function `f2()`, you can modify the code to not read it again and see if `gcc` will optimize accordingly:

```
int f1(const char *p) {
    char c = *p;
    if (!c)
        return 0;

    f2(); //not inlined

    if (c) { //should be always true
        //do something
        return 0;
    } else {
        //should be optimized out
        //do something else
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, but this is the solution I was trying to avoid. I want something more automatic than creating a local copy of the data every time I want this behavior

Comment: @gcc-question: did you try changing the definition to `int f1(const char * restrict p)` ?

Comment: See this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346301/does-const-t-restrict-guarantee-the-object-pointed-to-isn-t-modified/

Answer (score 2):

Have you disassembled the build to make sure that it is? Try the **restrict** keyword along with `const` to ensure that the compiler knows that nothing else can change it; you're calling another function **f2()** the compiler cannot know whether there is another pointer to the same block of memory being used in `f2`. But only do so as long as nothing in this branch does modify the same block of memory.

Your `if(!p[0])` seems dangerous BTW if `p` has been initialised to `NULL` - there is nothing to dereference.

Comment: `const` is irrelevant here, but `restrict` might do the job.  The precise semantics of `restrict` are so obscure I am not sure it should.

Comment: @chqrlie au contraire... `restrict` is one of the few things that has a precise mathematical specification, so we don't end up debating the intent of words

Comment: It can be both.  It can be simultaneously precisely defined _and_ not widely known.

Comment: @M.M: I dont pretend it does not, I'm just saying that IMHO the semantics are difficult to understand.  For instance, I do not understand what it means to qualify pointer arguments with `restrict` in function declarations, as is the case in the standard header files.

Comment: @chqrlie as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819855/is-top-level-volatile-or-restrict-significant-in-a-function-prototype) I think it has no effect other than as documentative to the person reading the header file (or to automated tools doing static analysis for example)

Comment: @chqrlie you probably know this but for clarity, the restrict keyword simply tells the compiler that within the given scope (including branches downward), only that the restricted pointer will point to the given block of memory. So nothing else accesses the same block of memory - it's exclusive to the pointer. So in this sense access is restricted to the given pointer.

Comment: @cdcdcd: I agree that this is the general idea, but the precise semantics in C11 *6.7.3.1 Formal definition of `restrict`* are so abstruse I cannot be sure that there is to it.

Comment: @M.M: that was my understanding, but this is both useless and deceptive.  For example: `memcpy(ptr, ptr, 0);` is perfectly OK, yet passing identical values for 2 restrict qualified pointer arguments seems incorrect.  The `restrict` keyword in standard function prototypes does not improve readability, au contraire: `FILE *fopen(const char * restrict filename, const char * restrict mode);`... Why would `const char *r = "r"; return fopen(r, r);` pose any problem?

Comment: Your `fopen` call is correct since neither string is written. (`restrict` is a promise that if the pointed-to object is written, it will only be read or written  through that same pointer (or a pointer based on it). It's like impromptu strict aliasing for objects of the same type

Comment: @M.M:  In the case of the declaration of `fopen`, I just cannot understand what promise `restrict` is supposed to indicate.

Comment: @chqrlie nothing, afaics, as far as the programmer is concerned... I guess that if you were writing the implementation of fopen, it would mean the compiler can update its `FILE` structure or whatever else it uses without risk of corrupting the arguments

Comment: @M.M: I agree with your interpretation, but it would have the unneeded side effect of making `char *r = "r"; fopen(r, r)` invoke undefined behavior.